# How do I transfer minecraft PE from one Android to another

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I asked this earlier and for some reason it was considered a question for the author but it is not my question is how do I transfer Minecraft PE from my Android phone to my son's Android tablet

Answer (score 1):

Only speaking from experience in the App Store here, but, if you guys both share an account on the Google Play store, it should be as easy as finding the app on the store, logging into your google play account, and downloading the game on the new tablet.